# Titanium Studio My Application does not launch in Android emulator

Tags: titanium

I am new to Titanium studio and bothered by a problem: I installed Titanium sdk 1.7.1, android 2.2,android 2.1 updates on mac 10.6.6 and I am able to successfully launch android emulator but emulator does not launch any of my application even kitchen sink example..

Comment: what is the error in titnanium studio?

Comment: Kitchen sink example shows: [ERROR] Failed installing com.appcelerator.titanium :pkg: /data/local/tmp/app.apk Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY]       and my appliciation shows this message : process appliationName has stopped unexpectedly, please try again

Comment: This is the solution http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/35751/error-failed-installing--pkg-datalocaltmpappapk

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan i have some related problem can you help me out...

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/160100/android-emulator-is-running-but-app-is-not-launching

Answer (score 0):

[INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY] - this error says that application tries to use libraries, that your system doesn't contain. In most cases it tries to use Google API's (and KitchenSink too). So open 'tiapp.xml' in your project, click 'configure...' link and under 'Android' section choose android version with Google API's in 'Default Android SDK' text box. If no version with Google API's - install it using AVD.